# Hashed lists in R, recovering a key given a value(vector)

Tags: r, hash, k-means

I am working on implementing k-Means in R.

I computy my feature vectors from individual files and put them all into a bag which I called "holder" in this fashion:

```
holder[[filename]] <- c(featureVector)
```

I can then recover a given feature vector if i write:

`holder[["file3453.txt"]]` or `holder[[number]]`.

I will be using the feature vectors for centroids and some other computation, so assuming that I have a feature vector V, how do I get the name of the file from holder?

This question could also be interpreted as:

**Given the value(feature vector) how can I determine the key(filename) ?**

Comment: You may be aware that k-Means is widely implemented in R.

Comment: There is no generic, efficient solution to this. the naive approach (just loop over your list elements and try to see if the value match until you find it) is good enough for most applications, especially if the number of keys is low. If this is not good enough, then creating a reverse map is essential and will save much time, but creating it maybe an issue in itself depending on the contents of your vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But why lose that connection between label and vector in the first place to need a reverse lookup? Just keep them together, and you won't have this problem:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(filename = c('a', 'b'), feature = list(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4)))
dt
#   filename feature
#1:        a   1,2,3
#2:        b   2,3,4

# possibly set the key to filename for fast access
setkey(dt, filename)
dt['a']    # this does a fast binary search lookup in data.tables

# modify the feature in some way for each filename:
dt[, feature := awesome_func(feature), by = filename]

# etc
```

Comment: A very nice solution. Similarly, you could use the `rownames` of a matrix to store the filenames. A matrix of the feature vectors is a more natural (more expected by machine learning functions) way of storing features than a list of vectors.

Comment: How to get the file name of vector 1,2,3 ?

Comment: @user2827159 why are you intent on losing that info? keep them together from the beginning and don't lose that connection

Answer (score 2):

To extend nograpes' solution. if you want to build a reverse map you can do the following:

```
#this function converts a feature vector
#there may be other, better ways to do that, but this one is simple.
#it works best when your feature vectors are short and contain integers
#it may not work at all due to precision issues for real numbers
my.to.string = function(x) paste(x,collapse="_")
```

when building your holder vector do this:

```
holder[[filename]] = featureVector   #updates the holder
reverseMap[[my.to.string(featureVector)]] = filename   # updates the reverse map
```

now - to get your task done just do

```
my.file = reverseMap[[my.to.string(my.feature)]]
```

This is straightforward, and will work for simple cases. It cannot replace a real hashcode based data structures which I haven't yet seen or needed R.

Comment: There's a `hash` package on CRAN (though I haven't used it personally).

Comment: @Peyton: thanks. I didn't know, but as I said, I am yet to encounter cases in which I really need it.

Comment: @amit One thing this solution doesn't allow is the same `featureVector` in two different files. A simple solution would be to check a `filename` exists already for a given `featureVector`, and concatenate (instead of replace) if it did.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that lists are not implemented with a hashtable in R. Also, there is no efficient way of doing what you want, you would either have to maintain a reverse lookup list, or just scan for matching indices. For example,

```
# Test data.
holder<-list(`file1`=c(1,0,1,0),`file2`=c(1,1,1,1),`file3`=c(1,0,1,0))
# Find this feature.
feature<-c(1,0,1,0)
# Find all indices that have this feature vector.
names(holder)[sapply(holder,function(x)all(x==feature))]
```