# R get vector from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two minor questions. This code below:

```
dt<-data.table(filename='asd.txt',vector=c(2,3,6))
```

**1. Replicates the filename three times and gives it values: 2,3,6. How to make it so that filename will be associated with ONE vector, instead of three values?**

**2. How to, given a vector v1, extract the "filename" from the data table ?**

Comment: `data.table(filename='asd.txt',vector=list(c(2,3,6)))` note the extra `list`, and this is really a duplicate of your previous question - maybe you need to specify your problem better

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hashed lists in R, recovering a key given a value(vector)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281021/hashed-lists-in-r-recovering-a-key-given-a-valuevector)

Comment: I closed that while only later noticing it actually didn't answer how to extract the file name given a vector, which was my main question. Your response was very qualitative but I didn't find my answer there, could you give me a hand on this by showing an example of how to do it, if it is possible ?

Comment: you can always uncheck the answer - as I said there I think the approach of trying to find filename for vector is misguided and you should not "lose" that info to begin with

Comment: I am new to R and what you explaiend makes perfect sense! The example you have allowed me to find a vector of a filename, not the other way around (I tried to play around but didn't manage to get it). Using your example, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and collapse that list:

```
DT <- data.table(fn='asd.txt',v=list(c(2,3,6)))
DT[,vchar:=paste(v[[1]],collapse=''),by=1:nrow(DT)]
setkey(DT,vchar)
#         fn     v vchar
# 1: asd.txt 2,3,6   236

v1 <- c(2,3,6)
DT[paste(v1,collapse='')]$fn
```

If the values in your list are longer than a character, you'll probably want to change the delimiter, e.g., to `collapse='_'`, in both places it appears.

Comment: I see your old question already has useful answers, so feel free to delete this question if you resolve your problem there.